# Q: Converting hostname to IP from a dictionary for netmiko connection?

Tags: python-2.7

In the past, I was able to do something simple like this to read a file
of IP addresses that I would iterate through to SSH to each one

```
# Grab the list of devices from a text file
devices = open('./devices.txt','r').read().split('\n')

# Connect to each router and do a show run command
for device in devices:
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(device_type="cisco_ios", ip=device, username="myusername",
                             password=password)
```

This time, however, I need to do something a bit more complex.

I pull some data from a JSON source where I can derive a "hostname."
But I cannot connect to the "hostname."  If the hostnames were in DNS
that would be easier but sadly they are not.

So.. I have a list of hosts to IPs that I figured I could use and pull
into a dictionary.

But now I somehow need to match up the hostname that gets derived from
the JSON data to match against a switchname in the hosts.csv so that I can
then basically convert hostname to IP so that I can then iterate through each
device in devices to SSH into each one.

This is all I have so far. I'm stuck at this point. Not sure how to match
things up to get the IP to use in my net_connect statement.

```
# Creat dict mapping hostnames to IP address for devices
with open(r'hosts.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        switch = {}
        switch_line = line.split(',')
        switch = {
            'ip': switch_line[1],
            'switchname': str(switch_line[0]).strip('\n')

# Define list of devices to connect to and the config changes to be made
pa = []

# This data is coming from a JSON source
for device in devices:
    if device['switchParent']:
        hostname = device['switchParent']
    else:
        hostname = device['destDevice']
        # hostname technically is the device I need to connect
        # however it needs to resolve to an IP from the switch dict earlier
        net_connect = ConnectHandler(device_type="cisco_ios", ip=hostname,                                                          
                                username="myusername", password=password)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `switchname` has a unique `ip` address then you should parse the `hosts.csv` file this way:

```
# Create dict mapping hostnames to IP address for devices
switch = {}
with open(r'hosts.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:       
        switch_line = line.split(',')
        switch[str(switch_line[0].strip())] = switch_line[1]
```

Then you go through the JSON data source:

```
# This data is coming from a JSON source
for device in devices:
    if device['switchParent']:
        hostname = device['switchParent']
    else:
        hostname = device['destDevice']
        # hostname technically is the device I need to connect
        # however it needs to resolve to an IP from the switch dict earlier
        net_connect = ConnectHandler(device_type="cisco_ios", ip=switch[hostname],                                                          
                                username="myusername", password=password)
```

That should work IF `hostname` is expected to be one of the keys from the `switch` dict.